# Copy sentence to Clipboard using simple JS

Tags: javascript, html

Is there a **simple way/function** to copy a sentence to the *clipboard* with **JavaScript** (no flash or jQuery)?

The function must be supported in Chrome; others browsers don't matter.

Comment: Check the answers here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/400212/how-do-i-copy-to-the-clipboard-in-javascript?page=1&tab=votes#tab-top

Comment: @stark I have done that before I posted this question but the answers in there are not useful.

Comment: @Mia They are useful, especially [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/30810322/283863).

Comment: @Derek朕會功夫 I need a function which only has a button like `<div data-copy="Hi">Click to copy</div>`, the answers on there are with textareas and all that.

Comment: @Mia That is because to copy text into clipboard in JavaScript, you must have an editable space. The collection of answers there explained it pretty well. See [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/execCommand) for details.